# Mysql structure for dynamic form with custom field names

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel-5, relational-database

Forgive me if this question has been answered before, but I just couldnt find anything that specifically relates to my situation.

I have a process where an admin can create forms in the backend of my website with custom attributes and inputs. Each form created can be associated with multiple businesses, but a business can only have one form. So...

```
Form     ->(hasMany)->   Business
Business ->(belongsTo)-> Form
```

To make the form dynamic, I created another table to store the inputs for each form. So...

```
Form  ->(hasMany)->   Input
Input ->(belongsTo)-> Form
```

I am having issues trying to create a structure for storing and accessing submitted data as a group on a business-by-business basis. Suppose I wanted to access all the input data for a given business and group them by each complete submission?

$business->form->submissions

Here is my current structure, which works, but it does not "group" the submissions. I can only access each individual input value:

```
Forms
 - id (pk)
 - name
 - template

Forms_Inputs
 - name (pk)
 - form_id (fk)
 - type
 - class_name

Forms_Submissions
 - id (pk)
 - form_id (fk)
 - submission_id (fk)

Submissions
 - id (pk)
 - input_name (fk)
 - (varchar) value
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to group each submission and access them? FYI I am using Laravel 5.2.

Comment: What does ' "group" ' mean? It requires effort, but please write with words rather than scare quotes. PS How is join not what you need? Please give an example of something you want to do but can't, and what you've done to get close.